# Python: Multiprocessing imap & dynamically-created pools freeze

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Could someone explain why this code freezes (hangs forever),

```
import multiprocessing
def foo(x): return x
def main():
    print(list(multiprocessing.Pool().imap(foo, iter([1, 2, 3]))))
main()
```

While this variant works fine,

```
import multiprocessing
def foo(x): return x
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
def main():
    print(list(pool.imap(foo, iter([1, 2, 3]))))
main()
```

as with this one,

```
import multiprocessing
def foo(x): return x
def main():
    print(list(multiprocessing.Pool().map(foo, [1, 2, 3])))
main()
```

Incidentally, being able to dynamically create multiprocessing.Pool() at a non-initialization stage in the application, and then use imap would be really helpful. I tried stepping through it in `gdb`, and it seems frozen at `PyThread_acquire_lock` ... but I feel pretty out-of-element debugging at such a low level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug with Python 2.6.7, and has been fixed at least by Python 2.7.3.

This can be worked around by using my `vimap` package [ https://github.com/gatoatigrado/vimap ].